# Atributos de imagem do Aspx se perdem após mudanças via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, imagem, asp, atributos

Inseri uma imagem com valor scr e DescriptionUrl definidos no Aspx e 
estou alterando o valor de source(scr) e DescriptionUrl (longdesc) via Javascript;

Acontece que após o page_load os valores default retornam e o que foi alterado via javascript se perde.

Neste caso, qual a melhor solução?

ASPX e JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function MudarCheckbox(id) {
  $("#" + id).attr("longdesc", "novaDescricao");
  $("#" + id).attr("src", "novaUrl");
}

//Aspx
Dim minhaImagem As Image = Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder").FindControl("minhaImagem")
//Obtem controller da img sem as alterações em JS
```

```html
<asp:Image ID="minhaImagem" OnClick="javascript:MudarValor(this.id);" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="minhaUrl" DescriptionUrl="minhaDescricao" />
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Confirme se entendi correto, você está modificando a imagem por javascript mas ai quando você acessa a página pelo code behind continua com a imagem antiga no src?

Comment: Isso mesmo Felipe, na hora que recupero os valores editados pelo JS

Comment: você poderia usar outros eventos na tag Image, dê uma olhada e veja se consegue contextualizar https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Valeu Thiago, vou dar uma olhada. Em geral pelo que procurei aqui a solução será aplicar um HiddenField. Brigadoaoo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507622/setting-asp-net-button-attributes-client-side-and-read-attribute-value-server-si